# Set formControlName to Template Variable

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working in an Angular v12 project. I have a form with many controls. In my template, I'm creating loops to display these controls. The controls are displayed in blocks in various positions (so all the outer divs matter).

When I set up these loops with a span, it works fines and shows the value of control I need:

```
<div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let rowGroup of rowGroups">
   <div class="square" *ngFor="let group of rowGroup">
      <div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
         <div class="block" *ngFor="let j of [1,2,3]">
            <span>
              {{this.form.get(group+'-'+i+'-'+j)?.value}}
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But now, instead of a span, I want to be able to use a material input. But I need to be able to set the `formControlName` to the template variables (`group+'-'+i+'-'+j`).

```
<div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let rowGroup of rowGroups">
   <div class="square" *ngFor="let group of rowGroup">
      <div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
         <div class="block" *ngFor="let j of [1,2,3]">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
               <input matInput formControlName="{{VARIABLE(group+'-'+i+'-'+j) HERE?}}">
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to bind it as:

```html
formControlName="{{group+'-'+i+'-'+j}}"
```

So your html would be something as below:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form"> <!-- You would need this binding too  -->
  <div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let rowGroup of rowGroups">
    <div class="square" *ngFor="let group of rowGroup">
      <div class="d-flex" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
        <div class="block" *ngFor="let j of [1,2,3]">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input matInput formControlName="{{group+'-'+i+'-'+j}}">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**PS:** The above should work if `{{this.form.get(group+'-'+i+'-'+j)?.value}}` worked for you. In case if it doesn't work, please do share the `form` FormGroup structure defined in `ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax just worked for me `[formControlName]="group+'-'+i+'-'+j"`